# rsyslog doesn't write log to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, rsyslog

I'm new with rsyslog and kafka, and get some trouble when trying to get the following log stream worked.

```
nginx log -> rsyslog-imudp -> rsyslog-omkafka -> kafka
```

Here is nginx conf

```
log_format  jsonlog '{'
    '"host": "$host",'
    '"server_addr": "$server_addr",'
    '"http_x_forwarded_for":"$http_x_forwarded_for",'
    '"remote_addr":"$remote_addr",'
    '"time_local":"$time_local",'
    '"request_method":"$request_method",'
    '"request_uri":"$request_uri",'
    '"status":$status,'
    '"body_bytes_sent":$body_bytes_sent,'
    '"http_referer":"$http_referer",'
    '"http_user_agent":"$http_user_agent",'
    '"upstream_addr":"$upstream_addr",'
    '"upstream_status":"$upstream_status",'
    '"upstream_response_time":"$upstream_response_time",'
    '"request_time":$request_time'
'}';

access_log syslog:server=server_ip,facility=local7,tag=nginx_access_log jsonlog;
```

And rsyslog conf

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

module(load="omkafka")

template(name="nginxLog" type="string" string="%msg%")

if $inputname == "imudp"then {
        action(type="omkafka"
            template="nginxLog"
            broker=["localhost:9092"]
            topic="rsyslog_logstash"
            partitions.auto="on"
            confParam=[
                "socket.keepalive.enable=true"
            ]
        )
}
```

Unluckily I don't have any output in the consumer terminal

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic rsyslog_logstash --from-beginning
```

Maybe it's the template, but I cannot find much documents about it.

Answer (score 0):

use rsyslog-impstats module to check how many messages had your imudp received, and how many sent to omkafka.

Comment: thanks to your comments, I do find something useful in stats log! Using command `/etc/init.d/rsyslog start` doesn't send any stream to omkafka while command `rsyslogd` works fine as expected. To make it clear, the first one doesn't have this log `Thu Oct 13 09:45:09 2016: omkafka: submitted=6 maxoutqsize=3 failures=0 topicdynacache.skipped=0 topicdynacache.miss=0 topicdynacache.evicted=0`

Comment: You can add queue.name to you action and check the special queue stats, to determine if rsyslog send msgs into the queue.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging stop rsyslog and run it with:
rsyslogd -nd
(I suggest run in with rsyslogd -n and check your Kafka topic again and then debug it)

Probably you have had problem with SELinux that can be resolved with this:

```
sudo semanage port -d -t unreserved_port_t -p tcp 9092
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 9092
```